# Python pandas convert given local date time to time stamp with local time zone without day light saving

Tags: python, pandas

Following code is my code.

```
import pandas as pd
pd.to_datetime("2015-11-18 15:30:00+05:30").tz_localize('UTC').tz_convert('Asia/Kolkata')
```

it returns following o/p

```
Timestamp('2015-11-18 16:30:00+0530', tz='Asia/Kolkata')
```

where as I am expecting o/p as follows

```
Timestamp('2015-11-18 15:30:00+0530', tz='Asia/Kolkata')
```

How I can get correct timestamp?

Comment: This could be a bug!

Comment: Yes probabily. it is reported as [Bug](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/11708#issuecomment-159969484)